# Activating SpreadSheet Tab from Google Appscript in Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I am creating a new tab with addon in google sheets but that tab is not in focus or activated after being created

```
function setActiveSheet(sheet) {
  try{
    let sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    let toActivate= sheet.getSheetByName('Users').setActiveSelection('A1');
    Logger.log(toActivate);    
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log("...error activiting sheet....");
    Logger.log(e)
  }
}
```

Simply running this script from appscript console activates the tab but executing same with from addon executes successfully but does not activates the tab

```
 await google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(function (res) {console.log(res);})
.withFailureHandler(function (e) {console.log(e)})
.setActiveSheet()
```

Comment: Why is it necessary for it to be activated?  When you open a spreadsheet with a script it doesn't open a  user interface like when a user  opens a spreadsheet it simply get's opened on the server.  But you can still read and write data to the desired sheetss

Comment: I have tried your function running it from the console but I get an error. I assume that you are calling it from another function, but the variable `sheet` is overwritten and there isn't any sheet called `Users`. On the other hand, could you please share the full code to deploy the add-on and briefly explain the steps you have followed?